# Method setUp "not mocked" error when trying to test a button under Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-activity

I'm trying to write an Android unit test that tests if the pressing of an ImageButton within the MainActivity fires an intent to start another activity (Activity2). Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {
    private Intent activityLaunchIntent;

    public MainActivityTest(){
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activityLaunchIntent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(activityLaunchIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Tests that the button to launch Activity2 fires the correct Intent.
     */
    @MediumTest
    public void testLaunchButton_shouldLaunchActivity2() {
        startActivity(activityLaunchIntent, null, null);
        final ImageButton launchActivity2Button = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.launchButton);
        launchButton.performClick();

        // Ensure that the intent to start the Activity2 has been launched 
        final Intent launchActivity2Intent = getStartedActivityIntent();
        assertNotNull(launchActivity2Intent);
        assertTrue(launchActivity2Intent.getClass().equals(SettingsActivity.class));
        assertTrue(isFinishCalled());
    }
}
```

When I try to run the unit test from within AndroidStudio however, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setUp in android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.setUp(ActivityUnitTestCase.java)
```

Upon visiting http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked, I added the following to my build.gradle file:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

Now however, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.unittesting.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:24)
```

Incidentally, line 24 of MainActivityTest.java is:

```
activityLaunchIntent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Can somebody tell me what is going on here? Is this a simple fix? Or am I going about doing this in completely the wrong way. Thanks in advance for any help.